# React-hook-form doesn't change the form validity when React-Select is changed

Tags: reactjs, react-select, react-hook-form

I have a react-hook-form with a react-select:

- When I change the value of react-select, the form becomes both dirty and valid.
- The submit button is now enabled and the form can be sent.
- Once the form is sent, `useForm` defaultValue's are reset to the new values
- The submit button is disabled again, waiting for a change in the form.
- When I change again react-select value, the form is not dirty. The button remains disabled. Yet, the react-select value has changed.

I have tried almost everything: replace `onChange` by `setValue("name", value, {shouldDirty: true}`, etc.

Here is the code:

```js
import { useForm, Controller } from "react-hook-form";
import Select from "react-select";

const options = [
  { value: "joe", label: "Joe" },
  { value: "jack", label: "Jack" },
  { value: "averell", label: "Averell" }
];

type Data = { name: string; surname: string };
export default function Form({
  defaultValues,
  onSend
}: {
  defaultValues: Data;
  onSend: (data: Data) => void;
}) {
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    reset,
    getValues,
    control,
    formState: { isValid, isDirty }
  } = useForm({
    mode: "onChange",
    defaultValues
  });

  const onSubmit = (data: Data) => {
    onSend(data);
    reset(getValues());
    console.log("data sent!", data);
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
     
        <Controller
          control={control}
          name="name"
          render={({ field }) => (
            <Select
            {...field}
              value={field.value}
              options={options}
              onChange={(v) => field.onChange(v)}
            />
          )}
        />
      <input placeholder="surname" {...register("surname")}/>
    
     
        <button type="submit" disabled={!isValid || !isDirty}>
          submit
        </button>

    </form>
  );
}
```

How to fix this?

ps: here is also a sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-test-8tdq3?file=/src/FormController.tsx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the answer is that I needed to add a useEffect to reset the form values after the submission:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    if (formState.isSubmitSuccessful) {
      reset(getValues());
    }
  }, [formState, getValues, reset]);
```